# Error while deserilizing json in C#

Tags: asp.net, json

I am getting response in json like this

```
data={"Id": "234", "Name": "pinky", "MobileNumber": "", "ClassName": "Class1_Physics",   "DOBTime": "1990-04-11 15:46:38", "Landline": "", "Status": "Unmarried"}
```

I want to deserilize json and insert into table.
I have created 2 classes for it and using dll of Newtonsoft for deserilization.

```
public class JsonResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string DOBTime { get; set; }
    public string Landline { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class JsonResultRoot
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public JsonResult JsonResult
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(Data); }
    }
}
```

Code :
decodedUrl : store actual json data/string
    var JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(decodedUrl).JsonResult;

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON contains this `data=` part, then it is invalid JSON. You cannot deserialize it using JSON.NET library.

In order to deserialize this, you can simply clean this part out:

```
public class JsonResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string DOBTime { get; set; }
    public string Landline { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

// Usage:
jsonString = jsonString.Replace("data=").Trim();
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(jsonString);
```

Of course, in general it looks bad. You should only do it if "you are getting response in json like this" and you can do nothing about it.
If there is any possibility to make incoming format correct, then better do it.